# Loading content into a div using jQuery's load method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to load the contents into a div named `rightcontent` into my page from external `html files` using the `jQuery's load` method. Initially, there is no content in my div `rightcontent`, and as the user clicks some links, the texts are automatically loaded into that div.

Take a look at these snippets :

---

*In my web page:*

```
<div id="rightcontent">
</div>
```

---

*The same web page also contains links like these:*

```
 <a class="myajaxreq" href="pages/abc.html">Link I</a><br>
 <a class="myajaxreq" href="pages/pqr.html">Link II</a>
```

---

*The external javascript file contains these code:*

```
$('.myajaxreq').click(function() {
var myhref=$(this).attr('href');
$('#rightcontent').load(myhref);

return false;
});
```

---

When I check whether my javascript calls are made correctly using `alert(myhref)`, it works correctly. However, no content is loaded into the div. Help me out here !!

Comment: did you look at the debugger? to see if the request was launched and successful ?

Comment: I tried using the `alert(myhref)` script and the dialog box dispalys the links correctly. However, the contents from that link are not loaded successfully into the div.

Comment: You must look in the network tab of your debugger (chrome and firebug have one) to see if a HTTP request is sent, and if it's successful. Also, you can pass a callback to $().load() to see when it's complete. You can dig the jquery doc of load() for information about that

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you testing the code locally or on a server? AJAX requests won't work locally.

Comment: I was about to ask the same question, more precisely, are you testing the file directly from the disk, ie via file:// protocol ?

Comment: @Blazemonger: I am running it locally !!

Comment: Problem solved, then. Upload it to a server (and put everything in the right subdirectories) and it should work fine.

Comment: @Blazemonger: Do I need to use server like the one provided in xampp or wamp ?

Comment: Those will do. It doesn't matter what kind of webserver you use. If you're unsure how to set one up, that's a separate question (and might be more appropriate on http://serverfault.com )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you testing the code locally or on a server? AJAX requests won't work locally.

Upload it to a server (and put everything in the right subdirectories) and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$('#rightcontent').text(myhref);
```

instaed of

```
$('#rightcontent').load(myhref);
```

Comment: But that loads the filename which is called, eg `pages/abc.html` or `pages/pqr.html` into the div, and not the content from the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$(".myajaxreq").click(function(){

    $.get( $(this).attr("href"), function(page){

        $("#rightcontent").html(page);

    })
    return false;
})
```

Comment: @CSSS Can you use PHP? Try something server-side with PHP, like: <?php include("pages/abc.html"); ?>

Comment: I am not very good with PHP, but I have had my experiences with it. How can I do the above using PHP ? It wont provide any animations or effects !!

Comment: @CSSS No, it would load server-sided, you would just type `<div id="rightcontent"> <?php include("pages/abc.html"); ?> </div>`, but i said that just for a test case, to see if the path was correct...